# Linking indvls with their spouse across 3 buckets (tables)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

From a Bank_DB where each line is a customer with account/demographic info I've created 2 buckets:

1. *pure_savers*: people with a pension plan AND bank account
2. *non_savers*: people without a pension plan or account
3. *other*:people with a pension plan but no account, or vice versa (note I haven't specified this bucket, it's just intuitive they're in here if not in 1) or 2).

I want to retrieve the # of instances where:

1. a *saver* has a *non_saver* spouse
2. a *pure_saver* has a *pure_saver* spouse
3. a *non_saver* has a *non_saver* spouse

Where I'm at:

- I created 3 tables (**Total**, **NonSave** and **PureSave**) with 2 columns each (*person_id* and *spouse_id*)
- I'm using a `left join` with my **total** table as the left table (it makes visual sense to me but I'm open to other suggestions).
- The idea is, if for example, person_id_total = person_id_nonsave = spouse_id_nonsave, I'm saying "this person is a non saver with a non saving spouse"

The code below lays out the big table I want to pull from:

```
select *
from
(select a.personal_id_total, a.spouse_id_total, 
        b.personal_id_puresave, b.spouse_id_puresave, 
        c.personal_id_nonsave, c.spouse_id_nonsave 
    from
        (select * from Total)a
    left join
        (select * from PureSave)b
    on a.personal_id_total = b.personal_id_puresave
    left join
        (select * from NonSave)c
    on a.personal_id_total = c.personal_id_nonsave
)k
```

I'm just not sure if i should use a case statement or something else? When I try to do this for example:

```
    select case when person_id_nonsaver = spouse_id_nonsaver  then 'Non-Saver with a pure saver spouse'
```

I get an empty table of course I'm still new at this so I'm not sure how to make the match. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Why the sub-queries? Simply `select ... from Total t left join PureSave ps on ...`

Comment: With LEFT JOIN the empty result set means your `(select * from Total)a` is empty.